# React setState of useState hook successfully updating state, but not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update my old Todo List React app so that it uses hooks, and can't figure this out for the life of me. setTodos is successfully updating the state on load as shown in React developer tools, but the component doesn't re-render and a blank list of todos is displayed on the screen. Only when I add a Todo to the list does it re-render and all of the todos show up. Here's what I've got:

```
const App = () => {

// Todos are the only state in App
const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState([]);

// Fetches Todos from Firestore database on load
useEffect(() => {
    const initialState = [];
    dbTodos.get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const currentTodo = doc.data();
            currentTodo['id'] = doc.id;
            initialState.push(currentTodo);
        });
    });
    setTodos(initialState);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

// Add Todo
const addTodo = (title) => {
    const newTodo = {
        title     : title,
        completed : false
    };
    dbTodos.add(newTodo).then((doc) => {
        newTodo['id'] = doc.id;
        setTodos([ ...todos, newTodo ]);
    });
};
```

Here is the code I used before implementing hooks:

```
componentDidMount() {
    dbTodos.get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const currentTodo = doc.data();
            currentTodo['id'] = doc.id;
            setState({ ...state, todos: [ ...state.todos, currentTodo ] });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Please add code of JSX or wherever you render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your **setTodos** in **UseEffect**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    dbTodos.get().then((snapshot) => {
        const initialState = [];    // Also this you can move here

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const currentTodo = doc.data();
            currentTodo['id'] = doc.id;
            initialState.push(currentTodo);
        });

        setTodos(initialState);   /// here
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Wow this worked like a charm. Can you explain the logic behind this solution, and why my code wouldn't work?

Comment: Bacause dbTodos.get().then is called async that means in your solution the order call is
1. prepare empty array (initialState)
2. Set todos with array from initialState 
3. *dbTodos.get finished* adds items into array (initialState)

Comment: Ahh I see. The interesting part though is that the state _did_ contain everything it fetched on load, they just weren't being rendered. Seems like the state shouldn't have been changed at all with my code

Comment: @JimmyD yeah but that initialState was updated after setTodos which mean react doesn't catch that state change , imagine it like this
initialState is just reference in memory and that reference is set as new todos by setTodos and that memory is still accessible by that callback and thats why it is still updatable, but react rerenders when setTodos is called now when that variable changes

Comment: Ok that's makes so much more sense. Really appreciate the help man

Answer (score 0):

When you setState in useEffect then you have to add setState in dependency.
Instead of doing that use another arrow function and call it from useEffect.

use the code below

```
const App = () => {

// Todos are the only state in App
const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState([]);

// Fetches Todos from Firestore database on load
const fetchData = () => {
    const initialState = [];
    dbTodos.get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const currentTodo = doc.data();
            currentTodo['id'] = doc.id;
            initialState.push(currentTodo);
        });
    });
    setTodos(initialState);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);

// Add Todo
const addTodo = (title) => {
    const newTodo = {
        title     : title,
        completed : false
    };
    dbTodos.add(newTodo).then((doc) => {
        newTodo['id'] = doc.id;
        setTodos([ ...todos, newTodo ]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In useEffect you create empty array. Make a request. set empty array to state. When request was fulfilled you make changes in the array by ref. Therefore you see you array in dev tool and react does'n rerender you component.

```js
const App = () => {

// Todos are the only state in App
const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState([]);

// Fetches Todos from Firestore database on load
useEffect(() => {
    dbTodos.get().then((snapshot) => {
        setTodos(snapshot.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        })));
    });
}, []);

// Add Todo
const addTodo = (title) => {
    const newTodo = {
        title     : title,
        completed : false
    };
    dbTodos.add(newTodo).then((doc) => {
        newTodo['id'] = doc.id;
        setTodos([ ...todos, newTodo ]);
    });
};
```